# Pop-up is working but changing the main page as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, popup

Function: Enter a phone number (ex: 555-555-5555) into a text field. The text field prints the number out flat (hidden by CSS). Then Javascript picks up that number by ID and splits it apart by the hyphens and injects the array split up into a FoneFinder URL search string to display the results from that site in a pop-up window.

Problem: The pop-up is working fine, however when I click on the link to spawn the link it opens in the main page as well as the pop-up. The main page should not change.

The pop-up code works fine on other pages and doesnt overwrite the main page. It has to be how the javascript is injecting the html link into the page that is messing it up, but I cant figure out why.

Any help or insights would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

#target_num_result {
    display: none;
}

#target_num_search {
    font-size: small;
}

</style>


<!-- NewWindow POP UP CODE -->
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

  function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll) {
        var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
        var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
        winprops = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+wint+',left='+winl+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
        win = window.open(mypage, myname, winprops)
        if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4) { win.window.focus(); }
  }

</script>


<!-- Script to read the target phone number and split it by hyphens and show a Search link to Fonefinder.net -->
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#target_num').on('keyup', function() {
        var my_value = $(this).val();
        $('#target_num_result').html(my_value);
        var arr = my_value.split('-');
        $("#target_num_search").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=" + arr[0] + "&nxx=" + arr[1] + "&thoublock=" + arr[2] + "&usaquerytype=Search+by+Number&cityname= title=FoneFinder onclick=NewWindow(this.href,'FoneFinderLookup','740','680','yes');>!BETA!FoneFinder Search!BETA!</a>");
    });

});//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 180px">Phone #:</td>
        <td><label> <input class="text" type="text" name="target_num" id="target_num" /></label><span id="target_num_result"></span><span id="target_num_search"></span></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
 <label>
 <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />
 </label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what you've provided I don't see a popup, just a page with a form on it. Do you have an example with the popup?

Comment: the problem is when clicking `a` tag, browser goes href's address. and you want just popup and go href. so.. you should prevent default action with `a` link. just add `return false` in `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to add is the following:

```js
$('#target_num_search').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    NewWindow(url,'FoneFinderLookup','740','680','yes');
})
```

This way you can remove the `onclick` attribute and move the function call to js. See the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ev1vpw7/1/)

Comment: pardon me. but, this prevents `onclick` also. did you test it?

Comment: oh, missed a thing =) have a look at the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ev1vpw7/1/) -  The idea was to get rid of the `onclick` argument altogether and move the function call to js. That make the code slightly cleaner

Comment: thanks for your comment. However that's very nice example with jQuery way. (and still available without jQuery.)

Comment: Using the proper use of return false in the onclick statement suggested by Yourim Yi worked.

However I like the cleanliness of this approach as well.

Thank you both very much.

Comment: one more thing... in `$.on` you don't need `event.preventDefault()` just `return false;` (then jQuery call `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`)

Answer (score 1):

you should `return false` for prevents default action to go link 'href' when `onlick` event.

(please notes `,` - comma operator to whatever Function returns... It's just hack. don't use.)

BTW,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

#target_num_result {
    display: none;
}

#target_num_search {
    font-size: small;
}

</style>


<!-- NewWindow POP UP CODE -->
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

  function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll) {
        var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
        var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
        winprops = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+wint+',left='+winl+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
        win = window.open(mypage, myname, winprops)
        if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4) { win.window.focus(); }
  }

</script>


<!-- Script to read the target phone number and split it by hyphens and show a Search link to Fonefinder.net -->
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#target_num').on('keyup', function() {
        var my_value = $(this).val();
        $('#target_num_result').html(my_value);
        var arr = my_value.split('-');
        var html_tpl = "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=" + arr[0] + "&nxx=" + arr[1] + "&thoublock=" + arr[2] + "&usaquerytype=Search+by+Number&cityname= title=FoneFinder onclick=\"return NewWindow(this.href,'FoneFinderLookup','740','680','yes'), false\" target='_blank'>!BETA!FoneFinder Search!BETA!</a>";
        $("#target_num_search").html(html_tpl);
    });

});//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 180px">Phone #:</td>
        <td><label> <input class="text" type="text" name="target_num" id="target_num" /></label><span id="target_num_result"></span><span id="target_num_search"></span></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
 <label>
 <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />
 </label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do a return false statement in it but removed it because it wasnt working. Turns out my approach was very syntactically different than yours.